# using ng-if to secure different content on page angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security

I have `div1` and `div2`.
If a user is admin I want him to see both of them.
If a user is a simple user, I want him to see only `div2`.

I used `ng-if` (beacuse it removes the `div` completely, and not using `display:none`)
Is it safe? Can it be intercepted and/or changed by proxy tools and/or chrome developer tools.
I didn't find any info on that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since *all* AngularJs code is client side, directives like `ng-if` will *not* protect you from proxy tools that target HTTP.

So, it depends what you mean be *safe*.  If you are providing sensitive information from the server, then no UI pattern/tool will secure that information.

Usually in SPA applications, security is applied to the server API that the client is speaking to.  The UI should be treated as under the control of the user.

Comment: anf if the website is running SSL?

Comment: SSL terminates at the browser.  So it helps with Man-in-the-middle and proxy tools, but if somebody opens the JS console in the browser they have access to all the data.  So, it is best not to send it if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

if i exclude the security discussion/consideration, I would prefer to use ng-show instead. I will introduce relevant modal properties in angularjs controller and show/hide based on them in html page.

Yes, the client side code can be investigated say using chrome developer tool and firebug etc.

I second @Davin Tryon suggestion, and say that Better to secure contents on server side.

Comment: You can show/hide based on controller properties for ng-if, so I don't see a difference in that respect.

Comment: Intrinsic?  ng-if happens during the link phase, ng-show adds and removes css.  ng-if can be much, much better if you have many DOM elements because it will not link them.  This will speed up render time greatly.

Comment: True, I agree with you.