# angular - hiding admin data using ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app, where each time I try to access a secure route, I first send a request to the server to verify my token. If the token is valid, I send an object to the client with the user's details, and a field telling me whether the user is an admin or not. On some pages, I want certain divs to be seen only by admins, so I do this:

```
<div ng-if="userData.isAdmin">Admins Only</div>
```

Is this scheme of mine secure enough? I'm not sure, because hackers with sufficient knowledge in angular may try to change my variables. I did come across a similar discussion in the link below:

[using ng-if to secure different content on page angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362962/using-ng-if-to-secure-different-content-on-page-angular-js)

However, I don't quite understand what their conclusion is. Are they trying to say that client side apps simply aren't secure enough, or is there some better trick in angular that can give me what I need?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not very secure... nothing stopping anyone from going in the console and flipping `userData.isAdmin` to true.

Comment: It is not secure against someone fiddling around with the javascript debugger. The secure way is to fetch the admin data/content using `$http` or something like that.

Comment: Can you provide a simple code example of the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is, how it is done quite often - your admin.html looks like:

```
<div ng-if="userData.isAdmin">
<div ng-repeat="data in secureData">{{data}}</div>
</div>
<div ng-if="!userData.isAdmin">
Access denied
</div>
```

And you acquire data in controller: `secureData = $http('/api/secureData'...)`
Now, all you need is to add check on server for `/api/secureData` call.

So you secure data, not html templates.

Comment: I see your point, but if the secureData contains, for example, links that when you click them an event is broadcast to rootscope, will the hacker be able to mock the secureData in the debugger and broadcast that event?